# dynamically creating key/value of an object and exporting to CSV

Tags: powershell, ldap, pscustomobject

After getting a search result from an LDAP Server, i need to create a pscustomobject dynamically.

The Problem here is that some of the attributes are not set for all users.

this is why i cannot create the pscustomobject the traditional way.

```
Name = $($item.Attributes['givenname'].GetValues('string'))
Surname = $($item.Attributes['sn'].GetValues('string'))
```

The Attribute Name does not exist for all users and doing this throws an error.

How can i create the pscustomobject in this case where i need to add both key and value dynamically.

Here is what i have so far:

```
$vals="cn","tel","email","sn","givenname","ou"
$c.Bind()
$r = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest -ArgumentList  $baseDN,$Filter,$scope,$attrlist
$re = $c.SendRequest($r)

foreach ($item in $re.Entries) {

    foreach($attr in $vals){
   
        if($item.Attributes.Keys -contains $attr){
       
        $pskeys += $attr
    }}

    foreach($pskey in $pskeys){
    
        $data += [pscustomobject]@{
        $($pskey) = $($item.Attributes[$pskey].GetValues('string'))
    }}

    $pskeys = @()
}
```

givenname does not exist for all the users and this is why the pscustombject must be created dynamically.

I cannot use a HashTable or some kind of a List as duplicate values must be allowed. There are cases where the attributes sn and givenname are equal.

After hours of trying and failing i can only hope for the Wizards of Stackoverflow to show me how this can be achieved.

I need a pscustomobject where i can save the available attributes and skip the missing attributes dynamically. Is there a way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($item in $re.Entries) {
    $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    foreach($attr in $vals){
   
        if($item.Attributes.Keys -contains $attr){
       
        $pskeys += $attr
    }}

    foreach($pskey in $pskeys){
        foreach($item in $item[$pskey].Attributes.GetValues('string'))
        {
           $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $item.Name -NotePropertyValue $item.Value
        }
        
    }

    $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-Table
```

Comment: i though arraylist does not allow duplicates.. I will give it a try and let u know.

Comment: Add an IF statement and test for null.  Some of you rows must be empty.  For debugging I would add : $psKeys | Format-Table. I would do same with re : $re | Format-Table.  Something in code is not right.  format-Table is great for debugging it will enumerate through all types of objects.

Comment: Thank You, It works now. I had to use `$table = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList` That made it work

Comment: I got the Arraylist the way i needed it but i cannot export it to csv now. it is outputting `System.String[]` instead of the values. The Keys are being displayed correctly in the first row. I tried `$table | foreach-object {$_} |Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath`but no success. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: I think Attributes is an array and you need to use [string]::Join(",",@(1,2,3,4)).  Best way of figuring out what is happening to to use Format-Table to see properties.  Did you try $table | Format-Table?  And $item | format-table.  And $item | foreach { $_.Attribute | format-Table}}  Check the properties and see what is causing issue.

Comment: I just tried `$item | format-table` and `$item | foreach { $_.Attribute | format-Table}` the first one confirms that Attributes is indeed an array. I get `{cn, givenname, sn,...}` the second one has no output.

Comment: `$table | Format-Table` gives me `{email@address.com}`. curly brackets mean array so even though the values per Key per Row are singular, they are still a single element array. I tried `$newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName [string]$pskey -NotePropertyValue [string]$item.Attributes[$pskey].GetValues('string')` to save the properties as strings and not as arrays but it didn't work

Comment: Replace foreach-object {$_} with foreach-object {[string]::Join(",",$_)}

Comment: i did. format-table now shows one row as one array. `@{cn=val1; sn=val2; givenname=val3;...}`. Is there no way to make add-member add all the values as strings and not as arrays? all the values are singular values. no need for it to be in an array.

Comment: You need another for loop.  I updated code above

Comment: I solved it by making sure the properties are being saved as strings and not as arrays. For me that worked because all the values in my case are singular values. Your code would be the way to go if multiple values had to be saved in arrays. i posted my working code as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

I have gotten it to work!

The Trick was to enclose `$pskey` and `$item.Attributes[$pskey].GetValues('string')` in `$()`

Without `$()` `Add-Member` was adding the properties as Arrays and not as Strings.

Here is the working Code:

```
$table = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$c.Bind()
$r = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest -ArgumentList  $baseDN,$Filter,$scope,$attrlist
$re = $c.SendRequest($r)

foreach ($item in $re.Entries) {

    $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject

    foreach($attr in $vals){
   
        if($item.Attributes.Keys -contains $attr){
       
        $pskeys += $attr
    }}

    foreach($pskey in $pskeys){
    
        $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $($pskey) -NotePropertyValue $($item.Attributes[$pskey].GetValues('string'))
        
        }

    $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
    $pskeys = @()   
    
    }

$table | Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append -Delimiter ";"
```

Thank You jdweng for pointing me in the right direction.

`$table | Format-Table` on the console and the resulting CSV after the Export look flawless now.

My Problem is solved.