# Export appointment information in Exchange 2016 with Powershell over EWS to csv

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to export Exchange appointment information of specific users as CSV in Powershell.
The script almost works (I can see required information).

But I got 2 problems:

- Export to CSV does not work - I found some options I tried to adept, but failed (see below).
- When an appointment has no Location set (=empty) I receive an error:

[image]

The script without CSV-Export looks like that:

```
$users = Get-ADGroupmember -Identity "GR_Test" -Recursive | Get-ADUser

foreach ($user in $users) {

$StartDate = new-object System.DateTime(2022, 01, 01)
$EndDate = new-object System.DateTime(2022, 12, 31)

$dllpath = "C:\Install\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2016_SP1)

$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind

$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())

$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar,($user.UserPrincipalNAme))
$CalendarFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$cvCalendarview = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView($StartDate,$EndDate)
$cvCalendarview.PropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$frCalendarResult = $CalendarFolder.FindAppointments($cvCalendarview)
foreach ($apApointment in $frCalendarResult.Items){
     $psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
     $apApointment.load($psPropset)
    "Appointment : " + $apApointment.Subject.ToString() 
    "Start : " + $apApointment.Start.ToString()
    "End : " + $apApointment.End.ToString()
    "Organizer : " + $apApointment.Organizer.ToString()
    "Location : " + $apApointment.Location.ToString()
    "Required Attendees :"
    foreach($attendee in $apApointment.RequiredAttendees){
        "   " + $attendee.Address
    }
    "Optional Attendees :"
     foreach($attendee in $apApointment.OptionalAttendees){
        "   " + $attendee.Address
     }
    "Resources :"
     foreach($attendee in $apApointment.Resources){
        "   " + $attendee.Address
     }
    " "
}
}
```

First try was to use Out-File within the array with -append:

I set it before the last bracket like this:

```
Out-file appointments.csv -Append }
}
```

I got no result (empty).

---

Second try was the same with Export-CSV

```
Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\calender.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append}
}
```

in this case script stops asking for "InputObject"

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

---

Another try was to "put" the whole array in $output variable and export it.

```
$users = Get-ADGroupmember -Identity "GR_Test" -Recursive | Get-ADUser

$Output = foreach ($user in $users) {

$StartDate = new-object System.DateTime(2022, 01, 01)
$EndDate = new-object System.DateTime(2022, 12, 31)

$dllpath = "C:\Install\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllpath)
$service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2016_SP1)

$windowsIdentity = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$sidbind = "LDAP://<SID=" + $windowsIdentity.user.Value.ToString() + ">"
$aceuser = [ADSI]$sidbind

$service.AutodiscoverUrl($aceuser.mail.ToString())

$folderid = new-object  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar,($user.UserPrincipalNAme))
$CalendarFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarFolder]::Bind($service,$folderid)
$cvCalendarview = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView($StartDate,$EndDate)
$cvCalendarview.PropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$frCalendarResult = $CalendarFolder.FindAppointments($cvCalendarview)
foreach ($apApointment in $frCalendarResult.Items){
     $psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
     $apApointment.load($psPropset)
    "Appointment : " + $apApointment.Subject.ToString() 
    "Start : " + $apApointment.Start.ToString()
    "End : " + $apApointment.End.ToString()
    "Organizer : " + $apApointment.Organizer.ToString()
    "Location : " + $apApointment.Location.ToString()
    "Required Attendees :"
    foreach($attendee in $apApointment.RequiredAttendees){
        "   " + $attendee.Address
    }
    "Optional Attendees :"
     foreach($attendee in $apApointment.OptionalAttendees){
        "   " + $attendee.Address
     }
    "Resources :"
     foreach($attendee in $apApointment.Resources){
        "   " + $attendee.Address
     }
    " "
}
}

$Output | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\calender.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

In this case I got incomprehensible output like this:

```
"Length"
"52"
"27"
"25"
"57"
"20"
"20"
"11"
"1"
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Create a table like following code which uses Add-Member : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74733340/dynamically-creating-key-value-of-an-object-and-exporting-to-csv/74733936#comment131903917_74733936

Comment: Add in the foreach this line for debugging : $apApointment | format-Table which will list all the properties in the object.

Comment: Thanks for you advice @jdweng! Can you tell me where in the structure of my script I have to implement the table creation? I lack experience with that currently trying to find basic information on that topic so I understand how it works in your linked post.

Comment: You do not need to create a table.  Any variable will be enumerated using format-table and the output will be displayed on the screen.  In this case $apApointment will be displayed.